# Excel template's VBA code not working after I insert it into a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I create an Excel template with fixed format and VBA stored in.

Whenever I insert the Excel template into a new workbook, the VBA code will not follow and apply. Only the format follows.

Does anyone know why?

This is the code stored in Template.xltm. Under ThisWorkbook

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\ASUS User\Desktop\MP\source.xlsm"
ThisWorkbook.Activate


End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Columns(2).AutoFit
Rows().AutoFit
End Sub



Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim wBook As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set wBook = Workbooks("source.xlsm")

If wBook Is Nothing Then
'The Workbook Is Not open'
' Nothing to do as workbook is not open
Set wBook = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
Else 'Workbook is open
' Close the workbook and save any changes
Workbooks("source.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
Set wBook = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
End If
End Sub
```

Does VBA code in excel macro enable template follows the template?

Comment: What is the extension of your file ? Did you save it as xltm

Comment: i save it a template.xltm

Comment: Where is your VBA code saved in the `.xltm` workbook? Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include more detail about your problem. As it currently stands it is very difficult to know why your template is not working as desired. Try and create a [mcve] so we can test it on our own machines and give a sample of your VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your workbook is saved as a Macro-enabled template, with the file extension `.xltm` instead of the standard `.xltx` template extension.

Comment: my file is template.xltm